# Powershell using Regex finding a string within a string

Tags: regex, powershell, substring

Need help using regex and powershell to accomplish the following.
I have the following example string:

```
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="site2pstoretoken" VALUE="v1.2~04C40A77~23"\><INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_error_code" VALUE="">
```

The only thing I want to extract from this example string is the hash stored in VALUE.
The hash is very long so I need to catch everything between *VALUE=" ....HASH.... "\>*

How will the regex look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one with warning, that *parsing html with regexes is bad idea*:

```
$regex = [regex]'(?<=VALUE=")[^"]*'
$regex.Match('te2pstoretoken" VALUE="v1.2~04C40A77~23"\><INP').Value
```

Edit:
And this code works as well:

```
if ('te2pstoretoken" VALUE="v1.2~04C40A77~23"\><INP' -match '(?<=VALUE=")[^"]*') { 
   $matches[0] 
}
```

Comment: @stej: What's the difference between using Match().Value and Match().Groups[index].Value