# Ctrl-F like regex in powershell?

Tags: regex, powershell

In Atom, if I use <kbd>Ctrl-F</kbd> with regular expressions, it will highlight all the matches of the regular expression, for example

File:

```
aaa
b
ccc
d
e
f
gg
```

Query:

```
[a-z]{2,}
```

Highlighted text:

```
aaa

ccc



gg
```

But I haven't found a cmdlet to do this in PowerShell

Expected input/output:

```
$var = @"
aaa
b
ccc
d
e
f
gg
"@

$var -find "[a-z]{2,}"

#Output
aaa
ccc
gg
```

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @NekoMusume No.

Comment: Remember to use google... Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726074/powershell-using-regex-finding-a-string-within-a-string answer your question?

Comment: I tried `$regex = [regex]'[a-z]{2,}'` and `$regex.match($var)` and got incorrect result

Comment: `.match` only gets the first result, `.matches` gets multiple. Is that what you want?

Comment: `$regex.Matches($var)` still gives me a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is

```
$regex = [regex]'[a-z]{2,}'
$regex.Matches($var).value
```

---

#### Explanation:

As in the comments I suggested you look at [Powershell using Regex finding a string within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726074/powershell-using-regex-finding-a-string-within-a-string) where the answer demonstrated the `[regex]`'s datatype `.match` method. Unfortunately, this only grabs the first result of a regex and is not meant for multiple results, however, `matches` **will** get multiple as it is the plural form of match:

`.match`:

```
# Define a regex query
$regex = [regex]'[a-z]{2,}'

# Define your variable
$var = @"
aaa
b
ccc
d
e
f
gg
"@

# Query $var
$regex.match($var)
#output


Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 0
Length   : 3
Value    : aaa
```

As you can see this only gets `aaa` and provides other data like what group it was in, if it succeeded, and other information.

However, if we do the same thing but with the `matches` method, it will get all 3 results:

```
$regex.matches($var)
#output


Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 0
Length   : 3
Value    : aaa

Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 6
Length   : 3
Value    : ccc

Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 16
Length   : 2
Value    : gg
```

Which shows information for all three results. But if we want to narrow down the results to just the values, we can grab the value tag of the variable like

```
$regex.Matches($var).value
#output
aaa
ccc
gg
```

Which is (I assume from your question) what you want.

Comment: If I want value and length, what do I do?

Comment: Like `@(@{Length = $regex.Matches($var).length}; @{Value = $regex.Matches($var).value})`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7) to get your desired output:

```bsh
$var = @"
aaa
b
ccc
d
e
f
gg
"@
$var -split '\r\n' | Select-String -Pattern "[a-z]{2,}"
```

Output:

```
aaa
ccc
gg
```